# Конкурентность и сеть

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, сеть, golang, сокеты

У меня есть сервер чата на сокетах и возникли некоторые проблемы, однозначно решить которые так и не вышло.

1. Отложенные действия у подключенных клиентов.

   Например: после получения определенного сообщения нужно переместить клиента в другую комнату чата, но если в до истечения периода клиент отключится, то получится, что переместится несуществующий клиент. Я пробовал решать это при помощи mutex'ов, но постоянно получал дедлоки, потому что эти задачи довольно глубокие и могут выполняться некоторое время. Второй вариант, через который это работает сейчас - создание некоторого пула задач, который проверяется постоянно при получении каких-то данных, (возможно, можно перенести в пинг) но в таком случае нельзя ручаться на время, заданное для выполнения задачи.
2. Как правильно контролировать авторизацию/деавторизацию клиентов? Так же выполнять это в отдельной очереди?

   Например: клиент авторизуется, случается какая-то проблема с соединением, но сервер уже начал его принимать (добавлять в комнату), в этот момент уже он авторизуется заново и получается, что онлайн оказывается еще и дубликат.
3. Единственно верное решение определять потерявшего соединение клиента - таймаут и пинг?

Comment: Добро пожаловать. У вашего вопроса несколько проблем. Во-первых, вопросы принято задавать по одному. Во-вторых, в вопросах принято показывать код и спрашивать про конкретные проблемы в этом коде. Подробное руководство [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: по третьему вопроса - да.

Comment: 2. После авторизации клиент может запоминать к примеру что-то вроде куки (лимитированный по времени секретный код). Далее любой запрос от клиента сопровождается этим самым куки. Так к примеру работает Sharepoint Federated Auth.

Answer (score 0):

№1 пример

- Логически разделить - соединение (присутствие и т.д), авторизацию, бизнес логику (перемещение по комнатам).

Т.е. сетевое соединение с клиентом != (не есть) авторизированный клиент != клиент в бизнес логике.

Я представляю следующий поток событий:

- Сетевое соединение `(source:port, client:xxx, authcode:xxx)`
- Проверка авторизации или новая авторизация `(source:port, client:uid-123, (authcode:bigsecret1234, expiration:in-24hrs-after-connect))`. В случае обрыва/ восстановления соединения меняете `(source:port)` все остальные параметры остаются в силе (пока куки в силе).
- Перемещение по комнатам и пост сообщений происходит в домене `(client:uid-123)`. Т.е. независимо от параметров соединения и авторизации в системе. Вы перемещаете клиента а не соединение. Соединения приходят и уходят ваш клиент никуда не девается. Пока он не теряет авторизацию или не удалятеся из системы.

И покажите код...